# App iOS se crashea al crear un Picker

Tags: ios, swift

Al momento de crear un Picker con SwiftUI y crear un ciclo forEach para pasarle cada una de las opciones, el preview se crashea y me sale el error:

Cannot preview in this file
iDine crashed

El codigo:

```
//
//  CheckoutView.swift
//  iDine
//
//  Created by Robert Ramirez on 24/04/23.
//

import SwiftUI

struct CheckoutView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var order: Order

    
    let paymentTypes = ["Cash", "CreditCart", "iDine Points"]
    @State private var paymentType = "Cash"
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Section {
                Picker("How do you want to pay?", selection: $paymentType){
                    ForEach(paymentTypes, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Payment")
        navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}

struct CheckoutView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CheckoutView()
            .environmentObject(Order())
    }
}

    
Se creo un log, no he podido descifrar el error, el log es extenso.
```

Comment: El error es en el preview, pero al ejecutar la app funciona?

Comment: Tampoco funciona al ejecutarla

Comment: Como no sé qué tiene `Order` hice un demo con tu código. Funciona si le agregar el punto `.` a `navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)` -> `.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)`.

Comment: Si era eso, se me había pasado, no sé por qué Xcode no ofrece un modo más simple de señalar el error.
Gracias!